# STM32 in app programming (IAP), custom bootloader

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, bootloader

I have attached all my codes in the link below; please review.

There Two programs Program **A** and **B**;
Prog A  is the **Application Image**
Prog B suppost be **bootload program**

Prog A has Memory address assigned to **0x08004000**

After reset, when Button is **Pressed** MCU goes in Prog B (at **0x08000 000**) and toggles LED at **1s**

However when button is **not pressed**, MCU doesn't seems to be running program 
Please check the debug log in attachments.
Anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The Bootloader needs to setup clocks and Interrupts precisely. If Bootloader enables the clock then Application should not do the same thing again.
 It is always best practice in Bootloader to reset the SYS TICK Timer , disable all the peripheral Interrupts before jumping to the Application.

Another thing you might want to consider is the size of your bootloader. If it exceeds 4000(H) bytes then your application would not start.